# Azure Service Bus - is it a good solution for peer-to-peer messaging platform?

Tags: azure, architecture, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

We are designing a system where users can exchange "messages" (let's say XML files for simplicity sake). This system is peer to peer by design - meaning only **directed** messages are supported. User A can only send message to User B, it is not possible to send messages to "groups" of users etc. FIFO order is mandatory requirement as well.

This must be a reliable solution - so we started looking into Azure and its services. And [Service Bus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-overview) does look like the right solution to me. It offers all bells and whistles we are looking for:

- FIFO order is guaranteed
- Dead-letter queue with timeouts
- Geo-redundancy
- Transactions
- and so on

So naturally, I started playing with it. And the first idea I had was to give each user of my system a **QUEUE** from the service bus. It will act as an `INBOX` for them. Other users send messages to the user (let's say using unique `USER_ID` as a queue ID for example), messages get accumulated in the queue and when user decides to check the inbox, they will get all the messages in the correct order. This way we "outsource" all routing, security etc etc to the service bus itself - thus considerable simplifying the app logic.

But there is a serious caveat in this approach - Service Bus supports only up to 10,000 queues: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted#capacity-and-quotas and the number of users in my system can reach tens of thousands (but max out at 100,000 or so). So I'm somewhat in the range but not really. Therefore, I have questions:

1. Is there a flaw in my approach? Overall, is that a good idea to give a queue to the user exclusively? Or perhaps I should implement some kind of metadata and route messages based on it?
2. Am I looking at the right solution? I want to use SaaS as much as possible so I don't want to start building RabbitMQs on VMs etc - but are there built-in alternatives? may be a different approach should be considered?..

As for the numbers, I'm looking to start with 2,000 users and 200,000 messages a day - not a high load by any means. But if things work out, I see how these numbers can increase by 20x - 30x (but no more).

I would appreciate any options on this. Thank you.

Comment: Max queues is per service bus namespace, so you could have a front-end component that looks up the namespace for each user before delivering the message.   This would also give you infinite horizontal scale, and multi-region.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft thank you. The way I see it currently, namespace is essentially "brand new" Service Bus. So they can't share dead-letter queue for example. Or am I wrong? Can I combine multiple "namespaces" somehow into single "group" so I can iterate through them in my Azure Functions?.

Comment: It would be custom.  Like Azure Function accepts a message and a UserID.  For each incoming message lookup the Namespace and Queue from a custom store (CosmosDB, Azure SQL, etc), possibly cached, and send the message to the queue.